# how to extract required data from xml

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping

I am trying to do some web scraping examples. I download data from a website and the data consists of xml and its look like this

```
ValCurs Date="20.04.2016" name="Official exchange rate">
<Valute ID="47">
<NumCode>978</NumCode>
<CharCode>EUR</CharCode>
<Nominal>1</Nominal>
<Name>Euro</Name>
<Value>22.4023</Value>
</Valute>
<Valute ID="44">
<NumCode>840</NumCode>
<CharCode>USD</CharCode>
<Nominal>1</Nominal>
<Name>US Dollar</Name>
<Value>19.7707</Value>
</Valute>
.
.
.
.
.
```

there are more than 25 currencies.

I want to extract only the currency name and the value which represent exchange rate. I have data for 50 days and I want to calculate the average exchange rate of every currency for these 50 days.
I download the data and save in xml files. and my code is as follow.

```
import os
import requests as rq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET


def saveData(path, date):
    session = rq.session()
    url = 'https://www.bnm.md/en/official_exchange_rates?get_xml=1&date=' + date
    datastore = session.get(url)
    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(datastore.content)
    value = ET.fromstring('/home/robbin/Desktop/20.04.2016.xml').find('Name/value')
    if value:
        print 'Found value:', value.text

def main():
    dates = ['20.04.2016', '21.04.2016', '22.04.2016']
    paths = []
    for date in dates:
        path = '/home/robbin/Desktop/{}.xml'.format(date)
        paths.append(path)
    for path, date in zip(paths, dates):
        saveData(path, date)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I got this error:
raise err

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0
```

My problem is that I am unable to extract the Name and value data from this xml data. I saw some examples on SO and internet but they are quite different from my case. If someone can help, It would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fromstring(...)` parses the string given. So it parses the path instead of the xml content.

Should be:

```
value = ET.fromstring(datastore.content).find('Name/value')
```

Working example:

```
def saveData(path, date):
    session = rq.session()
    url = 'https://www.bnm.md/en/official_exchange_rates?get_xml=1&date=' + date
    datastore = session.get(url)
    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(datastore.content)
    data = ET.fromstring(datastore.content)

    for element in data.iter():
        if element.tag in ('Name', 'Value'):
            print("%s - %s" % (element.tag, element.text))
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it is not returning or printing anything on the screen and nabaz mention that xml is not properly formatted. I got this data from a website and site is given in the url in the code

Comment: thanks a lot, it is working now and I can extract values from xml tags. you save my day. hav a nice day

Answer (score 0):

if you coped the xml correctly here, the issues is the xml is not formatted properly. The first line 1 and the column 0 is where the issue is. There should be an opening tag "<" at the beginning.

Comment: I got this data from a website and above every page this info is given.   "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below."...........I dont know how to format it correctly. Any idea. the website is given in the url in the code.